# How can I delete a value in a list inside a list of dictionary using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of dictionaries like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "apple",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "pear",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
]
```

I need to delete a specific value in the values array, so for example if I supply a function with

```
private deleteData("apple", 1)
{
    ....
}
```

My data becomes:

```
[
    {
        "name": "apple",
        "values": [2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "pear",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
]
```

What is the easiest way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Hi, can you please share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the target object using [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and then remove the element from `values` using [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "apple",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "pear",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
];

function deleteData(name, value) {
  const target = data.find(e => e.name === name);
  if(target) {
    target.values = target.values.filter(e => e !== value);
  }
}

deleteData('apple', 1);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let dict = [
    {
        "name": "apple",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    {
        "name": "pear",
        "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
];


function deleteValue(name, value)
{
  const filter = e => e !== value;
  for(let i = 0; i < dict.length; i++)
  {
    if (dict[i].name == name)
      return dict[i].values = dict[i].values.filter(filter);
  }
}
deleteValue("apple", 2)
console.log(JSON.stringify(dict));

deleteValue("apple", "3")
console.log(JSON.stringify(dict));

deleteValue("pear", 3)
console.log(JSON.stringify(dict));
```